# How to organize external JavaScript files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have inline JS that is specific to the view it's in, but the code is long enough that I would like to move it to an external script. However, I don't know how to do this without polluting my scripts folder*, nor do I know what to name it.

Currently I have two folders:

- `~/Scripts` for libraries (jQuery, etc.). This is where Visual Studio puts these by default so I've left it that way.
- `~/Scripts/Custom` for JavaScript used in more than one view.

I'm considering creating a folder for each controller and/or its views, which would look like
`~/Scripts/Custom/[Controller]`. Does this bring up any maintainability concerns?

* If I put everything into `~/Scripts/Custom`, I will end up with a bunch of files that look like `client-create.js`, `client-edit.js`, `ticket-index.js`, etc. This is more difficult to navigate than a folder structure and puts useless junk in front of what could be a useful file name.

Comment: Why not just use the `/Scripts/Custom` folder?

Comment: @Stephen Because then I have a ton of files that I'd have to organize by file name alone (`client-edit.js`, `client-create.js`).

Comment: Then its up to you if you want a more complex folder structure. Your asking for an opinion which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: This really depends on your application. If the chance of name collision is low then `/Controller/View` might work for you. If your application grows you might have controllers with the same name. You also might need to consider if any of these scripts need to reference each other -- more folders will make that more difficult.

Comment: @Stephen Is maintainability always subjective? I can tell you objectively that using copy-and-paste to put the same inline script into every page is difficult to maintain.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question in the last edit :)

Comment: Use this links to get some idea, my preference is feature folder structure that give business value
https://johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/

Comment: @Stephen Good point, I'll flag for a close. I don't suppose you could tell me where I *could* bring opinion-based questions?

Comment: No where on SO as far as I know. And I doubt a realist opinion could be given with out know a lot more anyway (how many files do you have?, why separate file for create and edit views? etc) - and even then its still an opinion (mine might be different from yours or someone else's)

Comment: @Stephen Gotcha. I considered the opinionated nature of the question, but decided getting input from a few patient, experienced developers was worth the downvotes -- and was hopeful this would differ from a "best practice" question, which I suppose it really doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

create one js file for one controller. For example if you a ClientController, create one Client.js, treat your js files as javascript controllers.

This is a maintainable approach and I have worked on several huge projects using this approach.

[image: screenshot of the folder structure from a project I work on]

[image: another project which I am currently working on]

screenshots from some projects i have worked on. The first project is pure .net mvc based project and the other project has angularjs on the frontend and .net on the backend.

Furthermore, what comes out of the box in a new mvc project makes the application complicated when it grows so its always better to customize your architecture according to the best practices(but still this is just my opinion).

Hope my answer helps you in some way.